# what is the best way to read big data and pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, memory

suppose I have two very big hdf files and I am going to read them and concat.

```
data = pd.concat([
pd.read_hdf("file1.hdf", key='data'),
pd.read_hdf("file2.hdf", key='data')
])
```

suppose every file take 10G of memory, and as we know, the above code will take a
peak memory usage of 40g. But the problem is that my computer's memory is only
32g, I wonder if there is any good way to read them and concat inplace so the peak
memory usage would be 20g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Pandas I'd input a [chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html) parameter. This will create an iterator of your data that you can go through.

Alternatively, try pyspark or dask. Dask is essentially pandas, but let's you both parallelize your pipeline and not load in the entire dataset.

Comment: I see, for some purpose chunksize would be a good solution. I just wonder if I can cancat inplace.